# How to test if a function grows logarithmically?

Tags: ruby, rspec, tdd, bdd

I have function in my model that counts user's score:

```
def score
  (MULTIPLER * Math::log10(bets.count * summary_value ** accuracy + 1)).floor
end
```

My point is to test that it grows logarithmically?

Comment: just to clarify the question: Do you want to test if the function score is O(log(n)) in the variable bets.count ? Not sure I understand.

Comment: I want to check that function return value grow logarithmic in variable of `bets.count`.

Comment: if you want to prove analytic, this is a math question and is off topic. If you want to prove numerically, you can use a graph plot gem, like rplot, and is not constructive - you can save this question editing it and prove me wrong.

Comment: Seconding the need to clarify if you want to "test" or "prove".  Also, what have you tried, or what ideas have you rejected?  I mean, you know how to test things in general, yes?  Why can't you apply that to this?

Comment: I know how to test, but I don't have idea how to generallly test that function grow logaritmically. I don't want to test against exact value, but against it growth.

Comment: @ŁukaszNiemier plot it agains some numbers and look at the graph - graph will give you answers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point of a test isn't to prove it always works (this is the area for static typing/proofs), but to check that it is probably working. This is normally good enough. I'm guessing you are doing it for a game, and what to ensure the function doesn't "grow" too quickly.

A way we could do that is to try a number of values, and check whether they are following a general logarithmic pattern.

For example, consider a pure logarithmic function `f(x) = log(x)` (any base):

If `f(x) = y`, then `f(x^n)` = `f(x) * n`.

So, if `f(x^n) == (f(x) * n)`, then the function is logarithmic.

Compare that to a linear function, eg `f(x) == x * 2`. `f(x^n) = x^n * 2`, ie `x^(n - 1)` times bigger (a lot bigger).

You may have a more complex logarithmic function, eg `f(x) = log(x + 7) + 3456`. The pattern still holds though, just less accurately. So what I did was:

1. Attempt to calculate the constant value, by using `x = 1`
2. Find the difference `f(x^n) - f(x) * n`.
3. Find the absolute difference of `f((x*100)^n) - f(100x) * n`

If (3)/(2) is less than 10, it is almost certainly not linear, and probably logarithmic. The 10 is just an arbitrary number. Most linear functions will be different by a factor of more than a billion. Even functions like `sqrt(x)` will have a bigger difference than 10.

My example code will just have the `score` method take a parameter, and test against that (to keep it simple + I don't have your supporting code).

```
require 'rspec'
require 'rspec/mocks/standalone'

def score(input)
    Math.log2(input * 3 + 1000 * 3) * 3 + 100 + Math.sin(input)
end

describe "score" do
    it "grows logarithmacally based on input" do
        x = 50
        n = 8
        c = score(1)

        result1 = (score(x ** n) - c) / ((score(x) -c) * n)
        x *= 100
        result2 = (score(x ** n) - c) / ((score(x) -c) * n)
        (result2 / result1).abs.should be < 10

    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Though I almost forget complex math knowledge, it seems the fact can't stop me answering the question.

My suggestion as follows

```
describe "#score" do
  it "grows logarithmically" do
    round_1 = FactoryGirl.create_list(:bet, 10, value: 5).score
    round_2 = FactoryGirl.create_list(:bet, 11, value: 5).score
    # Then expect some math relation between round_1 and round_2, 
    # calculated by you manually.
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Generally speaking, the best way to see if a function grows is to plot some data on a graph. Just use some graph plotting gem and evaluate the result.

A logarithmic function will always look like this:

[image: log func image]
<sub>(source: [sosmath.com](http://www.sosmath.com/algebra/logs/log4/log004.gif))</sub>

You can then adjust how fast it grows through your parameters, and replot the graph, until you found yourself happy with the result.

Comment: I know how to choose constants that will fit for me, but I need to test that no one ever change this to one that isn't logarithmic.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to treat this function like a black box, the only true solution is to get a bunch of values and see if their curve is well-approximated by a logarithmic curve, focusing on large `n`.  If you could put reasonable bounds on it, like `a log(n) < score(n) < b log(n)` for some values `a` and `b` then you could just check that.